# How can i do a division operation in gsp page.

Tags: grails, gsp

I want to do a division operation in GSP page.

When I do:

`${odimatches.count}/${totalmatches.count}`

I should do a division and want to get percentage out of it. When I tried above thing as usual it just displays 10/20 while rendering the page.

Comment: Where you want to use this?

Comment: @user1791574 in a gsp page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
${(odimatches.count / totalmatches.count)}
```

Comment: Great! Glad you got it sorted (might be a good idea to accept the answer, and perhaps upvote it if you can).

Comment: yes i am aware of it, i could do it, but i tried that way before reading your answer. thats by i didn't upvote. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
${(instanceOne.valueOne / instanceOne.valueTwo)}
```